# How can I check if an element's class is active in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have the following code:

View:

```
<li class="active"> 
    <a href="#public1' data-toggle="tab"> All Stacks </a>
</li>
```

I can locate the element (tab) in the following manner:

```
var allStacksTab = element(by.linkText("All Stacks"));
```

Now how can I test, using the expect() --to see if that element/tab has the active class?

Comment: You can first get the element <li> and then you'll be able to check class attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you grab the element as you did in your example you should be able to do the following or something similar...

```
allStacksTab.getAttribute('class').then(function (allClasses) {
    expect(allClasses.indexOf("className") > -1).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: can you explain the >0 part of your snippet?

Comment: good spot. It should have been > -1. The indexOf function will return -1 if it isn't found. You could alternatively remove the "> -1" and use .toBeGreaterThan(-1) I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use by.cssContainingText, and if you using ES6 - it even simplier:

```
let allStacksTab = element(by.cssContainingText("li", "All Stacks"));
// split(' ') is needed since class might be 'inactive' 
// and includes applied to string will return false positive 'true' in such case
let hasActiveClass = allStacksTab.getAttribute('class').then(classes => classes.split(' ').includes('active'))
expect(hasActiveClass).toBeTruthy('Element "All Stacks" should be active')
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.

```
expect(element(by.linkText("All Stacks")).element(by.xpath('..')).getAttribute('class')).toEqual('active')
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way to check if the class contains active:

```
var allStacksTab = element(by.linkText("All Stacks"));
allStacksTab.getAttribute('class')).toContain('active');`
```